# Rows of orthogonal matrices are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

How do I prove that rows of orthogonal matrices are also orthogonal?

By definition, orthogonal matrix means its inverse is equal to its transpose, but I don't see where the row orthogonality would come from.
And also, if **A** has orthogonal rows, is it correct that the matrix **A** is also orthogonal?

Comment: Once you know the definition $AA^T=I$, all you need to do is to interpret this equality in terms of rows of $A$, which boils down to understanding the matrix multiplication as scalar product.

Comment: Write down $AA^T=AA^{-1}=I$, and note that the $(i,j)$th enetry will be the dot product of the $i$th row of $A$ and the $j$th column of $A^T$ which is the $j$th row of $A$, the converse is not true you need the rows to be orthonormal for the matrix to be orthogonal

Comment: As for the converse, one also needs the rows to have unit norm (dot product of each row with itself is one).  Two rows can be orthogonal without having unit norm (it just means their dot product is zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the rows of $\mathbf A$ be $\mathbf a_1, \ldots, \mathbf a_n$. Then the columns of $\mathbf A^T$ are $\mathbf a_1^T, \ldots, \mathbf a_n^T$. By definition the product $\mathbf P = \mathbf A \mathbf A^T = \mathbf A \mathbf A^{-1}$ is the unit matrix $\mathbf I = (\delta_{ij})$. But the entry $p_{ij}= \delta_{ij} $ of  $\mathbf P$ is given as the matrix product $\mathbf a_i \mathbf a_j^T$, the latter being the same as the scalar product $\langle \mathbf a_i, \mathbf a_j \rangle$. This gives the desired orthogonality relations for the row vectors.

The converse is also true. If the rows of $\mathbf A$ are orthogonal, then the above considerations show that $\mathbf A \mathbf A^T = \mathbf I$. Hence
$$\mathbf A^{-1} = \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf I  = \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf A \mathbf A^T = \mathbf A^T .$$

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking to prove the following: Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with columns that are orthogonal and have unit norm. Then the rows of $A$ are also orthogonal and have unit norm.

To prove this, suppose the columns of $A$ are $a_1, \dots, a_n$. First note that $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are linearly independent because if $$\alpha_1 a_1 + \dots + \alpha_n a_n = 0$$ for some constants $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$, then taking the dot product on both sides above with respect to $a_i$, we would get $\alpha_i = 0$. By linear independence, we can write any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a linear combination of $a_1, \dots, a_n$: $$x = \beta_1 a_1 + \dots + \beta_n a_n.$$ Taking dot product on both sides with respect to $a_i$, we would get $\beta_i = \left<x, a_i\right>$. This gives the representation: $$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \left<x, a_i \right> a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i^T x) a_i = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_i^T \right) x.$$ Because this is true for every $x$, we can conclude that $$\sum_{I=1}^n a_i a_i^T = I$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. This is the same as $AA^T = I$. It is now easy to see that the $(i, j)^{th}$ entry of $AA^T$ is precisely the dot product between the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ rows of $A$. Thus $AA^T = I$ implies that the rows of $A$ are orthogonal and have unit norm.